# OpenCV Invisible / Transparent Window

Tags: c++, opencv

Is it possible to create a window which displays what is underneath the window in OpenCV? I'm thinking of playing around with some video editing and would like to be able to have video clips that I can move to overlay them... could do some interesting things with it.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: The convenience GUI functions in OpenCV are rather rudimentary. For anything non-trivial (and this sounds like it), I'd just write my own UI. Even the docs say "...sometimes there it is required to try functionality quickly and visualize the results. This is what the HighGUI module has been designed for."

Comment: Thanks Dan, I had searched around a bit before for a pre-made solution and just wasn't sure if I'd been looking in the wrong places. If I get round to making it I'll upload the code :)